# Steam OpenId in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, steam

I have never done an openid application before. I did see that MVC 5 has some built in oauth sign ins. I was able to get these to work no problem, as they are already built.

But I am completely unsure how to get the steam openid to work in MVC. Does anyone have some sample code of there MVC Steam OpendID stuff? Or does anyone know a good tutorial for this?

Comment: Try here https://github.com/laedit/OwinOAuthProviders/tree/master/Owin.Security.Providers/Steam

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console and type:

```
Install-Package Owin.Security.Providers
```

Open your App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs, and add:

```
using Owin.Security.Providers.Steam;
```

Then, in the `ConfigureAuth` method, add:

```
app.UseSteamAuthentication("your API key");
```

You can get an API key from http://steamcommunity.com/dev.

A "Steam" button should be added to your login page.

Comment: And its is available through Nuget: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin.Security.Providers/

Comment: @JérémieBertrand Since you're the author of the code, you're the best person to take advice from, so could you look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079461/how-to-set-openid-url-parameter-in-owin)? Much appreciated

Comment: What if I don't have a `Startup.Auth.cs` file? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent tutorial on how to integrate openid with ASP.NET MVC, and it do have working code, and instructions. Please have a look and get going.

http://weblogs.asp.net/haithamkhedre/archive/2011/03/13/openid-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc3-dotnetopenauth-and-openid-selector.aspx

Hope this helps.