# How to set OpenID url parameter in OWIN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, owin, steam

I have this basic setup:

Http Request -> Hardware OpenWRT Router -> Apache -> IIS. Between Apache and IIS there's a simple `mod_proxy` config like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@mail.com
    ServerName steam.domain.com

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.9/ timeout=600 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.9/
</VirtualHost *:80>
```

The application itself hosted on 192.168.1.9 IIS works flawlessly except for one thing - when I've followed the guide from website then I'm having my Steam OpenID return url set to 192.168.1.9 instead of steam.domain.com. Host is in the OpenID query string, so I suppose that it can be changed somehow?

**Edit**: The issue is when I click `Steam` button on login view I end up with SteamCommunity login screen with `Sign In through Steam at 192.168.1.69` instead of `Sign In through Steam at steam.domain.com` as per picture: [image: issue]

Comment: I might misunderstood the question: the website is browsable at steam.domain.com publicly?

Comment: Yes, it is. But it's bare template with only your plugin installed, so I'm trying to find a way to see `Use Steam to login into steam.domain.com` instead of what I have now: `Use Steam to login into 192.168.1.69`, so I've checked the url to which I am redirected after clicking Steam button and it contains that local IP also. I'm trying to fix this somehow, but with no luck yet, so I'm hoping that we'll figure out something

Comment: it's look like the link is generated with the ip address instead of the domain. Is it because there is a redirection between the domain to the ip address?
I will test that on a "real" domain as soon as I can.

Comment: @JérémieBertrand thanks for all your help, much appreciated :) keeping fingers crossed and looking forward on the results!

Comment: Sadly I can't reproduce the problem, you can test it at http://steam.laedit.net. So the problem seams to be caused by the all the routing/redirecting and I think (correct me if I am wrong) that IIS doesn't know the domain name, only the ip address.

Comment: Just to be sure, the domain declared on steam for the API key is steam.domain.com?

Comment: Just checked the key and the domain is proper. I've also tried your link, and after logging in I got this error: [Error](http://i.imgur.com/Yui1Eds.png), the same error I get when I hardcode my domain instead of `Request.Host` variable in `OpenIDAuthenticationHandler.cs` file.

Comment: Also I've tried to get some help on my [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/589425/how-to-setup-properly-host-on-iis) on ServerFault, you can check it out to look on my config.

Comment: I've got the same error when i am not already login on the steam website. I will look into it.

Comment: After some research, the error is coming from a database problem, it's not the openId callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return url is build on the request launched when the user click on the link to authenticate himself via Steam:

```
private string BuildReturnTo(string state)
{
    return Request.Scheme + "://" + Request.Host +
        RequestPathBase + Options.CallbackPath +
        "?state=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(state);
}
```

In [OpenIDAuthenticationHandler.cs](https://github.com/owin-middleware/OwinOAuthProviders/blob/master/Owin.Security.Providers/OpenID/OpenIDAuthenticationHandler.cs).

So I think that the problem is just in dev (I assume the website is still in dev cause of the ip address 192.168, but I know nothing about Hardware OpenWRT Router and mod_proxy).

Comment: I've edited original post, hopefully this will be much clearer now.