# Steam openid authentication in MVC5 works only in localhost

Tags: localhost, asp.net-mvc-5, openid, steam

I am developing a website in MVC5 where users must be linked to their Steam accounts. I am trying to get steam openID authentication to work by following this post:
[Steam OpenId in MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079060/steam-openid-in-mvc-application)

When testing the website on localhost, everything works fine. A Steam button is added, when I click it I am redirected to the Steam login page, when I login there I am redirect back to my website and authenticated.

After deploying the website to my server however, it stopped working. I am still redirected to the Steam login, I login on their site, I am redirected back to my own website, but this time I am not authenticated.

I can see with Chrome developer tools that I am being redirected back to the 'ExternalLoginCallback' action with "error=access_denied" parameter. So somehow my access is being denied when the website is deployed, but it works fine on localhost.

Screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14309718/steam.jpg

I found a blogpost which seemed to deal with a similar problem (but for Google login): http://blog.technovert.com/2014/01/google-openid-integration-issues-asp-net-identity/

Their solution was to allow anonymous access to the "signin-google" location via the web.config, as you can read on the blog post. I tried to do the same (except for "signin-openidsteam", which is what I found in the developer tools, see screenshot), but it makes no difference.

What am I doing wrong?